# Connecting to twitch chat python

Tags: python, irc, twitch

```
import time
import win32api, win32con
import socket #imports module allowing connection to IRC
import threading #imports module allowing timing functions

#sets variables for connection to twitch chat
bot_owner = 'TheMagicalCake'
nick = 'MagicalCakeBot'
channel = '#TheMagicalCake'
server = 'magicalcakebot.jtvirc.com'
password = '~redacted~'

irc = socket.socket()
irc.connect((server, 6667)) #connects to the server

#sends variables for connection to twitch chat
irc.send('PASS ' + password + '\r\n')
irc.send('USER ' + nick + ' 0 * :' + bot_owner + '\r\n')
irc.send('NICK ' + nick + '\r\n')
irc.send('JOIN ' + channel + '\r\n')
```

I'm trying to make a bot for twitch chat but when I run this code I get the error I'm using someone elses code that works for them but not for me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/TheMagicalCake", line 47, in <module>
    irc.connect((server, 6667)) #connects to the server
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: Please tell me you're not creating a spambot for twitchplayspokemon...

Comment: No Im trying to make a stream similar to twitchplayspokemon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getaddrinfo failed` generally means that the hostname you are trying to connect to can not be resolved to an IP address. In this case, it probably means that it doesn't exist.

### Why?

When you pass `socket.connect()` a hostname instead of an IP address, it first needs to find the IP address of said hostname. It does this using `socket.getaddrinfo()`, which asks DNS servers for information about the hostname. It turns out that no DNS server has this information, so the call to `getaddrinfo` fails, hence the error message.

### How to connect to Twitch's IRC

The procedure of connecting to Twitch's IRC has changed a bit since your guide was made, it seems. Here's how I managed to do it.

- Get an OAuth token from [TwitchApps](http://twitchapps.com/tmi)
- Connect, with your twitch username, to `irc.twitch.tv`, port 6667. As password, use `oauth:` plus the oauth token you just got.
- Join the channel you are streaming on.

Comment: I'm using the name of my twitch bot like they did in the guide. I also  tried the channel i wanted to stream from which didn't work either. Do you know what the correct host would be?

Comment: I've updated my post with what seems to work now, your guide is a bit outdated it seems.